# How to Decrypt that LUA code?

Tags: encryption, lua

i cant get my self over this and i cant decrypt that code, i found few tools but they wont work for me.

Could someone decrypt that code?

```
loadstring('\27\76\117\97\81\0\1\4\4\4\8\0\16\0\0\0\64\116\111\66\121\116\101\67\111\100\101\46\108\117\97\0\2\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\11\0\0\0\5\0\0\0\6\64\64\0\65\128\0\0\164\0\0\0\28\64\128\1\5\192\0\0\6\64\64\0\65\0\1\0\164\64\0\0\28\64\128\1\30\0\128\0\5\0\0\0\4\19\0\0\0\69\102\102\101\99\116\77\101\115\115\97\103\101\80\114\111\120\121\0\4\10\0\0\0\79\110\82\101\99\101\105\118\101\0\4\11\0\0\0\68\105\99\101\69\102\102\101\99\116\0\4\17\0\0\0\76\111\99\97\108\83\112\101\101\99\104\80\114\111\120\121\0\4\11\0\0\0\83\97\121\67\97\116\99\104\101\114\0\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\11\0\0\0\0\5\0\9\17\0\0\0\69\1\0\0\70\65\192\2\128\1\128\0\197\129\0\0\198\193\192\3\220\129\128\0\1\2\1\0\213\1\130\3\92\129\128\1\90\1\0\0\22\0\1\128\133\65\1\0\134\129\65\3\193\193\1\0\12\2\194\2\156\65\128\1\30\0\128\0\9\0\0\0\4\7\0\0\0\115\116\114\105\110\103\0\4\6\0\0\0\109\97\116\99\104\0\4\5\0\0\0\83\101\108\102\0\4\5\0\0\0\78\97\109\101\0\4\16\0\0\0\32\114\111\108\108\101\100\32\97\32\40\46\43\41\46\0\4\7\0\0\0\83\105\103\110\97\108\0\4\5\0\0\0\83\101\110\100\0\4\11\0\0\0\68\105\99\101\82\111\108\108\101\100\0\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\17\0\0\0\6\0\0\0\6\0\0\0\6\0\0\0\6\0\0\0\6\0\0\0\6\0\0\0\6\0\0\0\6\0\0\0\6\0\0\0\7\0\0\0\7\0\0\0\8\0\0\0\8\0\0\0\8\0\0\0\8\0\0\0\8\0\0\0\11\0\0\0\6\0\0\0\7\0\0\0\115\105\103\110\97\108\0\0\0\0\0\16\0\0\0\8\0\0\0\109\101\115\115\97\103\101\0\0\0\0\0\16\0\0\0\2\0\0\0\120\0\0\0\0\0\16\0\0\0\2\0\0\0\121\0\0\0\0\0\16\0\0\0\2\0\0\0\122\0\0\0\0\0\16\0\0\0\14\0\0\0\82\111\108\108\101\100\95\78\117\109\98\101\114\0\9\0\0\0\16\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\14\0\0\0\18\0\0\0\0\5\0\8\8\0\0\0\69\1\0\0\70\65\192\2\129\129\0\0\202\129\0\0\201\129\128\129\201\1\1\130\92\65\128\1\30\0\128\0\5\0\0\0\4\7\0\0\0\83\105\103\110\97\108\0\4\5\0\0\0\83\101\110\100\0\4\11\0\0\0\65\110\97\108\121\122\101\83\97\121\0\4\9\0\0\0\99\114\101\97\116\117\114\101\0\4\8\0\0\0\109\101\115\115\97\103\101\0\0\0\0\0\8\0\0\0\16\0\0\0\16\0\0\0\16\0\0\0\16\0\0\0\16\0\0\0\16\0\0\0\16\0\0\0\18\0\0\0\5\0\0\0\6\0\0\0\112\114\111\120\121\0\0\0\0\0\7\0\0\0\6\0\0\0\109\116\121\112\101\0\0\0\0\0\7\0\0\0\8\0\0\0\115\112\101\97\107\101\114\0\0\0\0\0\7\0\0\0\6\0\0\0\108\101\118\101\108\0\0\0\0\0\7\0\0\0\5\0\0\0\116\101\120\116\0\0\0\0\0\7\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\11\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\11\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\14\0\0\0\14\0\0\0\14\0\0\0\18\0\0\0\14\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0')()
```

Comment: Quoting from [the book](http://www.lua.org/pil/2.4.html) "We can specify a character in a string also by its numeric value through the escape sequence \ddd, where ddd is a sequence of up to three decimal digits. As a somewhat complex example, the two literals "alo\n123\"" and '\97lo\10\04923"' have the same value, in a system using ASCII: 97 is the ASCII code for a, 10 is the code for newline, and 49 (\049 in the example) is the code for the digit 1."

Comment: This suggests that if you just change `loadstring` to `print` you'll be able to "decode" the data :-)

Comment: Looks like a precompiled chunk, so you have to get the bytes and then run it through a decompiler for your architecture.

Answer (score 1):

Using luadec

```
-- Decompiled using luadec 2.0.1 by sztupy (http://winmo.sztupy.hu)

EffectMessageProxy.OnReceive("DiceEffect",
   function(a0, a1, a2, a3, a4)
      local Rolled_Number = string.match(a1, Self.Name().." rolled a (.+).")
      if Rolled_Number then
         Signal.Send("DiceRolled", Rolled_Number + 0)
      end
   end
)
LocalSpeechProxy.OnReceive("SayCatcher",
   function(b0, b1, b2, b3, b4)
      Signal.Send("AnalyzeSay", {creature = b2, message = b4})
   end
)
```

Comment: thats perfect, one more code if you could do that for me, it's quite long so i just uploaded it to my site www.hostdev.pl/code.lua

Comment: @Rafau - Sorry, luadec failed to decompile such a large bytecode file.

Comment: My friend is pretty sure but he doesnt know to "decode" it, that in those few lines, there's somewhere hidden that name http://pastebin.com/Z0mNMVBj

p.s. here's first 700 lines of the previous code.lua www.hostdev.pl/dec.lua

Comment: @Rafau - Try simply replace `Self.Name()` with `"Abevian"`.  Yes, that means you have to replace old code `loadstring('\27\...\0')()` with new code `EffectMessageProxy.OnReceive("DiceEffect",...`.  This may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is not encrypted Lua code: it is precompiled Lua code. As suggested by Sean, save the bytes to a file. Then get Lua 5.1, build it in a 32-bit machine and run `luac -l` on the file you saved. You'll get this listing, which is not Lua source code but may help you reconstruct it if needed.

```
function <toByteCode.lua:2,20> (11 instructions, 44 bytes at 0x8c9dd00)
0 params, 3 slots, 0 upvalues, 0 locals, 5 constants, 2 functions
        1       [4]     GETGLOBAL       0 -1    ; EffectMessageProxy
        2       [4]     GETTABLE        0 0 -2  ; "OnReceive"
        3       [4]     LOADK           1 -3    ; "DiceEffect"
        4       [11]    CLOSURE         2 0     ; 0x8c9ded0
        5       [4]     CALL            0 3 1
        6       [14]    GETGLOBAL       0 -4    ; LocalSpeechProxy
        7       [14]    GETTABLE        0 0 -2  ; "OnReceive"
        8       [14]    LOADK           1 -5    ; "SayCatcher"
        9       [18]    CLOSURE         2 1     ; 0x8c9e228
        10      [14]    CALL            0 3 1
        11      [20]    RETURN          0 1

function <toByteCode.lua:4,11> (17 instructions, 68 bytes at 0x8c9ded0)
5 params, 9 slots, 0 upvalues, 6 locals, 9 constants, 0 functions
        1       [6]     GETGLOBAL       5 -1    ; string
        2       [6]     GETTABLE        5 5 -2  ; "match"
        3       [6]     MOVE            6 1
        4       [6]     GETGLOBAL       7 -3    ; Self
        5       [6]     GETTABLE        7 7 -4  ; "Name"
        6       [6]     CALL            7 1 2
        7       [6]     LOADK           8 -5    ; " rolled a (.+)."
        8       [6]     CONCAT          7 7 8
        9       [6]     CALL            5 3 2
        10      [7]     TEST            5 0 0
        11      [7]     JMP             5       ; to 17
        12      [8]     GETGLOBAL       6 -6    ; Signal
        13      [8]     GETTABLE        6 6 -7  ; "Send"
        14      [8]     LOADK           7 -8    ; "DiceRolled"
        15      [8]     ADD             8 5 -9  ; - 0
        16      [8]     CALL            6 3 1
        17      [11]    RETURN          0 1

function <toByteCode.lua:14,18> (8 instructions, 32 bytes at 0x8c9e228)
5 params, 8 slots, 0 upvalues, 5 locals, 5 constants, 0 functions
        1       [16]    GETGLOBAL       5 -1    ; Signal
        2       [16]    GETTABLE        5 5 -2  ; "Send"
        3       [16]    LOADK           6 -3    ; "AnalyzeSay"
        4       [16]    NEWTABLE        7 0 2
        5       [16]    SETTABLE        7 -4 2  ; "creature" -
        6       [16]    SETTABLE        7 -5 4  ; "message" -
        7       [16]    CALL            5 3 1
        8       [18]    RETURN          0 1
```

Comment: thanks, that's nice, but im not a LUA scripter or something, this is just a script i downloaded for BOT for Casino Sript for Tibia, it's supposed to be bound to nickname, and i believe this code i gave you guuys i key to that. I still can't see "Tiusu Frontline" anywhere, it's supposed to be nickname that's bound to that script.

Answer (score 0):

About this [large bytecode](http://www.hostdev.pl/code.lua)

Unfortunately, Luadec failed to decompile this bytecode.
But it [successfully disassembled it](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/98abdb7796fe135072fe/raw/Tiusu_Frontline_disassembled)

The name `Tiusu Frontline` is hidden.  But not hidden good enough :-)
On the following lines you can see the process of forming the string 'Tiusu Frontline' from ascii values of corresponding chars:

```
36865 [-]: LOADK     R6 K28       ; R6 := 84
36866 [-]: LOADK     R7 K29       ; R7 := 105
36867 [-]: LOADK     R8 K30       ; R8 := 117
36868 [-]: LOADK     R9 K31       ; R9 := 115
36869 [-]: LOADK     R10 K30      ; R10 := 117
36870 [-]: LOADK     R11 K32      ; R11 := 32
36871 [-]: LOADK     R12 K33      ; R12 := 70
36872 [-]: LOADK     R13 K34      ; R13 := 114
36873 [-]: LOADK     R14 K35      ; R14 := 111
36874 [-]: LOADK     R15 K36      ; R15 := 110
36875 [-]: LOADK     R16 K37      ; R16 := 116
36876 [-]: LOADK     R17 K38      ; R17 := 108
36877 [-]: LOADK     R18 K29      ; R18 := 105
36878 [-]: LOADK     R19 K36      ; R19 := 110
36879 [-]: LOADK     R20 K39      ; R20 := 101
36880 [-]: CALL      R5 16 2      ; R5 := R5(R6,R7,R8,R9,R10,R11,R12,R13,R14,R15,R16,R17,R18,R19,R20)
```

There are some more similar fragments in this disassembler output building the same string from the same ascii codes.
Probably, it would be not so hard to patch this bytecode file to change the name `Tiusu Frontline` to another one.

Comment: If you could just try for me with name "Abevian", or just teach me how to use LuaDec.

Comment: @Rafau - I have no experience in patching bytecode files.  You should create another topic to ask help on patching your bytecode file.  LuaDec is decompiler, it can't patch anything.  LuaDec is very easy to use: `luadec file.luac > file.lua`

Comment: still thank you, when i run luadec.exe it just close that cmd window instantly :s